# How do you handle a single quote in an asp.net web search

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How do you handle special characters in an asp.net web search with SQL Server back end database. For example, single quotes and double quotes, etc.

Comment: use escape char to handle `\'` slash single quote or `''` double single quotes or `\"`

Comment: I think parameterized SQL or using Entity Framework and stored procedure can overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the single quote `'` or double quotes `"` would be done like this

```
StrQuery = "Select * from TableName Where Keyword LIKE '%" + TxtSearchBox.Text + "%'";
StrQuery = StrQuery.Replace("'", "\'");
StrQuery = StrQuery.Replace('"', "\"");
StrQuery = StrQuery.Replace("\", "\\");
```

Another very important thing is you'd be better off using **Parameterized queries**. These will automatically handle the single quotes, and protect you better from SQL Injection.

**[SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)** would follow the ISO rules regarding quotation mark delimiting identifiers and literal strings. Identifiers delimited by double quotation marks can be either Transact-SQL reserved keywords or can contain characters not generally allowed by the Transact-SQL syntax rules for identifiers.